# Can I add $i in variable to call the same sequence variable?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$listing_weblinkurl_1z1 = "some1";
$listing_weblinkurl_1z2 = "some2";
$listing_weblinkurl_1z3 = "some3";
$listing_weblinkurl_1z4 = "some4";

for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++){
print ($listing_weblinkurl_1z.$i);
}
?>
```

It is not working. I know that it is wrong to add `$i` in variable to call it. But I want it.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using an array?

Comment: @McAden: it is POST form element name that is converted to variable. And i used it same as form element name.

Comment: @extremerose71, you can use `listing_weblinkurl[1z1]`, `listing_weblinkurl[1z2]`, etc to have PHP automatically create arrays with `$_GET` and `$_POST` input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how it would be done, using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i+= 1 )
{
  $varname = 'listing_weblinkurl_1z' . $i;
  echo $$varname;
}
```

However, this is not a good way of writing code. Instead, `$listing_weblinkurl` should probably be an array containing keys of `1z1`, `1z2`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) {
   print ( ${"listing_weblinkurl_1z$i"} );
}
```

As @McAden pointed out in the comments, it would probably be a better idea to use an array.